# "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification" does not want to go away

Tags: android, gradle

I've noticed today that I keep getting the following error in Gradle:

I have no idea which library is causing it. Ive tried to remove them one by one, or update ones I suspect, but no luck.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
compile 'com.googlecode.plist:dd-plist:1.16'
compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: The error should be underlined, when you hover over it what does it say?

Comment: send your logcat and full build.gradle file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the issue. Turns out its renderscript, as seen in this: 
https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView/issues/46

Hope this helps someone else out there!